# Joomla - using one model and one view for multiple tasks

Tags: joomla

I am making a simple component that responds with an XML message.

What I have now is:

```
controller.php
               models/
                     register.php
                     login.php
                     download.php
               views/
                     users/
                           view.xml.php
                     login/
                           view.xml.php
                     download/
                              view.xml.php
```

What I want is:

```
controller.php
               models/
                     users.php

               views/
                     users/
                           view.xml.php
```

The component will perform three operations, login, register and download.

How should I set this up?

ie.  controller will have three tasks  (login, register and download)
How will I get the data to the View?  Do I need three models?  Should I just output the xml from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep your models as those 3 and have a single view? You can call multiple models in a single view. Check this [post](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=316802) out.